# How does one display a Wordpress website within 'Static Html: iFrame Tabs' in Facebook so that it adjusts to the page's content height?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, iframe, facebook-apps, static-html

I have tried various solutions to get the iframe to adjust according to the website's content height, so that I can do away with vertical scrollbars, but cannot get a satisfactory solution.

Many solutions ask for a section of code to be added on the 'server side'. If that means I have to edit lines of code within my Wordpress files, where would I do this?

[Here is a link to the iframe in question.](https://www.facebook.com/du.designsoc/app_190322544333196)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try to adjust the Facebook page to fit your WordPress install, you're better off changing your WordPress theme to deal with being shown in a Facebook iframe.

When displayed in the iframe, you should have a theme that is fixed-width to your canvas, and no sidebars. Just a content pane. You would then have your regular theme for when visitors arrive outside of a Facebook frame.

The [Virtual Theme](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/virtual-theme/) plugin looks like it could help with this. I've never used it personally.